# Spring MVC Generics Object Binding/Type Conversion

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, generics, type-conversion

I'm looking for a way to wrap my models or DTOs with a generic class to add a 'selected' Boolean property and be able to bind the object in my POST method controller.

Like this:

```
public class RowForm<T> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private T model;
    private Boolean selected=false;

    public RowForm() {
        super();
    }

    public RowForm(T model) {
        super();
        this.model = model;
    }

    public T getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(T model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public Boolean getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(Boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

}


public class ProductsForm implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private RowForm<Product> row;

//...other stuff and getters/setters
}
```

and use it like this:

```
    @PostMapping ("/postProduct")
    public String POSTproduct(Model model, @ModelAttribute ProductsForm pf) 
    {
    ....
    }
```

But I'm stuck with the conversion...

When I call `pf.getRow()` it returns a plain `Object`, not a `RowForm<Product>`.

How can I implement a ConversionService/PropertyEditor to bind my posted data to my extended generic object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a abstract base class with the selected property, and extend it for your DTOs?